# Sql Server: Finding translation errors (rollback reason)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, transactions, rollback

Is there a way in SQL Server to view the reason a transaction failed?

I have a 3rd party application which is supposed to insert data into a database, but for some reason, one of the inserts fail, hence the transaction fails. I have used the profiler and am able to see the statement of the transaction. It looks fine, but I cannot figure out how to get the cause of the transaction rollback. I can see the identity of the transaction (based on the time it was executed) in the query below but cannot find a way of finding the reason for the rollback.

```
SELECT
[Current LSN],
[Transaction ID],
[Operation],
[Transaction Name],
[CONTEXT],
[AllocUnitName],
[Page ID],
[Slot ID],
[Begin Time],
[End Time],
[Number of Locks],
[Lock Information],
[RowLog Contents 1]
FROM sys.fn_dblog(NULL,NULL)
WHERE Operation IN 
('LOP_ABORT_XACT')  
order by [Begin Time] desc
```

I have checked the error log but that transaction does not seem to be present there.

How can I find the reason  the sql server rejected a transaction?

Comment: Do you have control of databse where you are getting error? Maybe you can  log query in database and execute in management studio, that would give you error detail. If you are using stored procedure you can use try catch to log exception

Comment: @JyotiVinayPandey I do have control of the database. By log query, do you mean using the server profiler and saving to a file/table? I did try that I and see the executed statement showing with error 0. However, there is still a rollback

Comment: Yes you can use raiseerror and log your error in a datatable, since you said that executing the query is giving no error its hard to predict. if this is happening occassionally with the same query you maybe facing deadlock.